# pytest-nodev: automatic permutation of arguments

Tags: python, pytest

I'm learning how to use [pytest-nodev](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/pytest-nodev) to search for the implementation of a function defined by a unit test. In the case of a function with two (or more) parameters, is there any way to automatically try all permutations of the input parameters?

For example, with the following test function:

```
def test_copysign_hit(wish): 
    copysign = wish
    assert copysign(2, 2) == 2
    assert copysign(-3, 2) == 3
    assert copysign(4, -2) == -4
    assert copysign(-5, -2) == -5
```

using the following command line:

```
py.test test_copysign.py --wish-modules math
```

I get a *hit* for the [`math.copysign`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/math.html#math.copysign).

But if I permutate the arguments in my test function, which is just an implementation detail, I don't get the *hit*:

```
def test_copysign_no_hit(wish): 
    copysign = wish
    assert copysign(2, 2) == 2
    assert copysign(2, -3) == 3
    assert copysign(-2, 4) == -4
    assert copysign(-2, -5) == -5
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The ability to permutate the arguments of a callable [is an enhancement request](https://github.com/nodev-io/pytest-nodev/issues/8), but it is not implemented at the moment.

As a work-around you could make more runs with minimal changes to the test function as in the following:

```
def test_copysign_hit(candidate): 
    # one run per permutation
    def copysign(a1, a2):
        return candidate(a2, a1)
    # original test
    assert copysign(2, 2) == 2
    assert copysign(-3, 2) == 3
    assert copysign(4, -2) == -4
    assert copysign(-5, -2) == -5
```